# Как задать минимальный размер токена для to_tsvector() функции в Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, полнотекстовый-поиск

Я разбираю документ на поисковые токены с помощью Postgres-функции `to_tsvector()`.
Однако, среди прочего, Postgres парсит токены, длиной менее трёх символов:

```
'1':89,91 '2019':14 '25':4
```

Я не нахожу их полезными, и не хотел бы хранить в БД. Есть ли какой-то способ установить минимальную длину токена для функции to_tsvector():?